# bind folders in fstab messing up permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem, home-directory, fstab

I'm configuring my system. I have an Ubuntu partition with the /home inside it (not extra partition for /home). I thought I could `bind` some folders from another partition on the same drive to my /home. My fstab is the following

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=34fefb4c-5d1f-4ea8-9a73-de0aeb6bf36d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7C7D-5744  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /media/data01 was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=5bb5bb6e-5694-431f-b4f4-9b7c14fc3f56 /media/data01 ext4 defaults 0 2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0df977ea-c9ee-4215-90a3-3b2f0d562b9d none            swap    sw              0       0
# /sdb1
UUID=256fcae8-8710-45e5-93d4-e91b1d05b9fe /media/data02 ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

# bind mounts
/media/data01/Audio /home/luca/Audio bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
/media/data01/Cloud /home/luca/Cloud bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
/media/data01/Desktop /home/luca/Desktop bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
/media/data01/Documents /home/luca/Documents bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Downloads /home/luca/Downloads bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Library /home/luca/Library bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Pictures /home/luca/Pictures bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Programming /home/luca/Pictures bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Public /home/luca/Public bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Software /home/luca/Software bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/SoftwareLibrary /home/luca/SoftwareLibrary bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Videos /home/luca/Videos bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
media/data01/Workspace /home/luca/Workspace bind defaults,user,bind 0 0
```

I ended up with mixed permissions and I don't understand why, as below

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 luca luca 4096 gen 30 10:00 Audio
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen 30 09:59 Cloud
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen 31 12:02 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen 30 09:59 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 luca luca 8980 gen  3 19:34 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Library
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen  5 11:53 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen 30 10:03 Programming
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Software
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 SoftwareLibrary
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 gen  5 11:53 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Videos
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 gen 31 11:57 Workspace
```

Notice that some default folders (e.g. Documents) are owned by luca, other default folders (e.g. Downloads) are owned by root. Some folders created by me (e.g. Cloud) are owned by luca while other folders also created by me (e.g. Library) are owned by root. It seems random.

I also tried to add the `user` option to the fstab line of /media/data01, with no success.

If I remember well when I installed my system, I ended up with data01 and data02 owned by `root:root`, and I changed that with `sudo chown -R luca:luca /media/data01`. Is this significant?

Is this due to the `defaults` options or other fstab options? How can I fix this so to have my data from my external partition binded to my home folder with all the right permissions?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: The permissions shown are not the permissions set on the mountpoint, but those on the mounted directories. Maybe this is the reason? `ls -l /media/data01` may show.

Comment: Those are the permission of `ls -l /home/luca`. The permissions of `/media/data01` are `luca:luca` for all the subfolders.

Comment: When I bind mount any directory to a mountpoint, the effective permissions/ownership of the directory are shown at the mountpoint, no matter what the permissions on the mountpoint was in advance. Are you sure the mounts did succeed? From `man mount`, there should be `none` in the fstype field of the `fstab`entry...

Comment: You appear to have specified an absolute path `/media/data01/...` for some and a relative path `media/data01/...` for the others